Enable Google Sign In in different Firebase projects based on build type
I have two build types for an Android app, Release and Staging. The Release build targets the production environment, while the Staging build targets the development environment. Both builds are signed with the same SHA-1 key, as they are essentially the same app.
Additionally, I have two Firebase projects, one for production builds and one for development builds. The idea is that the Release build targets the production Firebase project, and the Staging build targets the development project.
To enable Google Sign In through Firebase, I need to add apps to Firebase projects, and define the bundle and SHA-1 key. However, Firebase requires that for each Android app, I provide a package name and a SHA-1 key that is globally unique across all of Google Cloud.
So, I am unable to enable Google Sign In in different Firebase projects based on build type. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this, and what are the best practices for managing different build types of the same app that target separate Firebase projects?
